# Is there a way to disable Prettier from a cloned repo?

Tags: reactjs, prettier

Please it's 5 hours that I'm just trying to disable this stuff from a cloned [repo](https://github.com/lukemcdonald/holly-react) and still can't do it.

I tried everything but prettier still seems to be working.

I went in the setting and disabled it but it didn't work.

I then tried to go in the .prettierrc and give him a "enable":false bust still nothing

I also tried to just make a .prettierignore and put a * in it but it still works

Just tried to require a config file and delete mine BUT IT STILL WORKS PLEASE WTF

I'm going crazy, I can't believe something that stupid is so difficult to get rid of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with `.prettierignore` and write in that file this code

```
**
*.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go into .prettierrc.js file in your project(cloned project) `"endOfLine": "auto"`.

your file should look something like this after changes:

```
 module.exports = {
  semi: false,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  singleQuote: true,
  printWidth: 100,
  tabWidth: 2,
  endOfLine: 'auto',
}
```